# How to initialise closure variable in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my main struct. and I am trying to get a call back when listView selects and item.

```
struct Home: View {

    @State var selectdItem : Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            listView(onselecteditem: {selectdItem in
                self.selectdItem = selectdItem
            })
            resultView(selectedItem: self.$selectdItem)

        }

    }
}
```

And I would like to initialise my closure variable in init in this struct. it works without init, but i have to use the init.

```
struct listView : View
{
    var onSelectedItem : (Int) -> Void

    init(onselecteditem : (Int) -> Void) {

     // I would like to initialise onSelected closure variable here.   
    }

    var body : some View
    {
        List(1..<10)
        {
            item in
            Text("Item \(item)").onTapGesture {
                self.onSelectedItem(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without initialization, how are you able to compile?

Comment: @Kamran If I don't use init, struct will automatically initialise and I can use closure block to get values. but since I have to use init, I don't know how to manually assign values inside init block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize `closure` variable as,

```
init(onselecteditem : @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    self.onSelectedItem = onselecteditem
}
```